# Merge multiple PDF files with VBScript

Tags: pdf, vbscript, pdf-generation

I'm looking for a way to merge multiple PDF files into one with VBScript, only with Acrobat and Distiller - without using any third-party software. Although I really searched hard for a solution on the web, I couldn't find one. Can someone please help me out here?

Thank you!
S.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had success in the past using Acrobat's [Interapplication Communication](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/interapplication_communication.html) feature from VBScript.  I don't have a full version of Acrobat to test with, but this should at least give you a starting point:

```
Dim app
Set app = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")

Dim srcDoc, destDoc
Set srcDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")
Set destDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc")

srcDoc.Open srcPath
destDoc.Create
destDoc.InsertPages 0, srcDoc, 0, srcDoc.GetNumPages(), 0
destDoc.Save 0, destPath

srcDoc.Close
destDoc.Close
app.Exit
```

The OLE Automation section of the [API reference](http://livedocs.adobe.com/acrobat_sdk/9.1/Acrobat9_1_HTMLHelp/IAC_API_OLE_Objects.103.2.html#1526000) contains a list of the available classes and methods.

Comment: Hi Cheran, 
Thanks a lot, I will try that and get back to you.